# Using NSBlockOperation in Objective-C methods that use the target / selector pattern for callbacks?

Tags: objective-c, selector, objective-c-blocks

Occasionally I come across Objective-C methods that only use the target / selector pattern for callbacks in situations where it'd be much easier to use a block. One example is in `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:observer
                                                    selector:@selector(method)
                                                        name:@"name"
                                                      object:nil
                                   suspendedDeliveryBehavior:NSNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDrop];
```

It doesn't provide a corresponding method that takes a block instead. So in these sorts of situations I often use NSBlockOperation as the target:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
                                                                 // do something
                                                             }]
                                                    selector:@selector(main)
                                                        name:@"name"
                                                      object:obj
                                   suspendedDeliveryBehavior:NSNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDrop];
```

Is it safe to use `NSBlockOperation` in this way?

For example, is the `NSBlockOperation` instance guaranteed to persist for as long as it's needed, both when compiling with ARC and without?

Comment: Does `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` inherit `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` from `NSNotificationCenter`?

Comment: @Willeke I think it does, actually, and I didn't realize that. Though there is a method on `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` that includes the argument `suspendedDeliveryBehavior` and doesn't have a counterpart that uses blocks. I didn't include that argument in my example for simplicity, but I may edit my post to include it so that it's a more legitimate example.

Comment: The documentation of `addObserver:selector:name:object:suspensionBehavior:` says "The receiver does not retain notificationObserver.".